# A question which is easy geometrically but can we have a formal proof?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, geometry, analysis, solution-verification

Let $f(z)$ be an entire function and $Z_\epsilon(H)$ be the number of zeros of $f$ in the rectangle $R_{\epsilon}=\{x+iy\in\mathbb{C}\mid 1-\epsilon\leq x\leq 1+\epsilon, 0\leq y\leq H+\epsilon\}$ where $\epsilon>0$ is arbitrarily small. Let $Z(H)$ be the number of zeros of $f$ on the line $L=\{x+iy\in\mathbb{C}\mid x=1, 0\leq y\leq H\}$.

**Question:** Prove that $$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}Z_\epsilon(H)=Z(H) $$

**My try:** Take $\epsilon=\frac{1}{n}$ where $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and define $R_{n}=\{x+iy\in\mathbb{C}\mid 1-\frac{1}{n}\leq x\leq 1+\frac{1}{n}, 0\leq y\leq H+\frac{1}{n}\}$

Note that $R_n$ decreases with $n$ which means that they are sequence of decreasing sets with respect to set inclusion. So, since the sets $R_n$ are nested for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$, so taking the intersection of all rectangles we have $$\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} R_n=\{x+iy\in\mathbb{C}\mid x=1, 0\leq y\leq H\} $$
Is this idea correct? Is there another method?

Comment: The point is that zeros of an entire function are discrete (unless the function is zero). In particular there are only finitely many zeros in a given rectangle region. Once $\epsilon$ is small enough, all but those on the line are excluded from the rectangle.

Comment: @Whatsup Thank you. Can you please write an elaborate answer. I will accept it.

Comment: Don't you rather want to take the *intersection* of $R_n$'s?

Comment: @Berci Yes it was a typo, I have edited. Is my try correct?